# How do I make a POST call without encoding all of the data?

Tags: php, file, http, encoding, upload

I'm trying to emulate a POST call/fileupload so I can do it programmatically, rather than using a clunky outdated app.

The form field in my attempted emulation looks like this

```
<Input Type=text name="data" value="begin+600+%7B_TRACK_NAME_%7D%0D%0AM240S...">
```

According to my HTTP traffic analyzer, the original version posts like this

```
data=begin+600+%7b%5fTRACK%5fNAME%5f%7d%0d%0aM240S...
```

(it goes on and on, and it's a chunked upload, so there are dozens of these posts)

When I attempt my POST call (from a PHP form), it sends this

```
data=begin%2B600%2B%257B_TRACK_NAME_%257D%250D%250AM240S...
```

(on and on and on)

so, naturally the server side is stunned at my stupidity and says terrible things about me, and my loved ones, rather than accepting the file.

### Any ideas?

Well, the reason I haven't posted my code is because it's all literally just one PHP form post.  Meaning... I get the same error if I just take the data that I'm posting, and manually send it, rather than generating that data programmatically.

But, if it helps, the code I would use would look something like this.

``````
// Opening the file and loading into the variable $contents

$filename = "sample.mp3";
$handle = fopen($filename,"r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

// uu_encoding the string

$uu_string = convert_uuencode($contents);

// the first line BEFORE uu_encoding looks like
//  ID39TTrandomCOMengiTunPGAP0TENiTunes 10.5.1COMhe  
//  (it's an MP3)

// the first line AFTER uu_encoding looks like
//  M240S`@`````0.514,@``"`!R86YD;VT`0T]-```0`&5N9VE4=6Y01T%0

// url_encoding the uu_encoded string    
$url_string = rawurlencode($uu_string);

// the first line after url_encoding looks like
// M240S%60%40%60%60%60%60%600.514%2C...

<form action="target.aspx">
<Input Type=text name="data" value="<? echo $url_string; ?>">
<Input Type=Submit>
</form>
``````

---

When submitted, the POST call looks like this

If I submit this the server will respond "Error: Input String was not in a correct format.", which I believe is because the server is expecting data to be a certain format and length. So my aim is to figure out why my data doesnt look like the traditional "final" data, and the first step is figuring out why my data looks like that.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: can't you use `urldecode()` to fix it?

Comment: People will be much better able to help if you post a sample of the code that doesn't work and the actual error messages in which the server assassinates your character.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should use htmlspecialchars instead of rawurlencode. Urlencode is used for HTTP, not HTML, plus your data seems to be encoded already, so you just encode it twice.

Alternatively, you could use cURL to send the post from the server and avoid the HTML form mess altogether.

Comment: This doesn't work quite correctly. Although I've gotten closer and closer to a solution, the current problem is that url_encode isn't actually converting my +"."s to "%2e", it leaves them alone. 

Which is... maybe the problem. The PHP manual says that that's by design, but then W3Schools suggests that it SHOULD actually be converting those.